# How to make an outbound call with Twilio and detect if it has been answered

Tags: twilio

I am trying to develop a simple application with Twilio and I have some issues. I have the code made with Python to make the call.

```
def makeCall(self, phoneNumber, from_num, message):
        call = self.client.calls.create(
                        method='POST',
                        machine_detection='Enable',     
                        to= phoneNumber,
                        from_= from_num,
                        url= self.url + urlencode({'Message' : message}),
                        status_callback= self.url_callback,
                        status_callback_method = 'POST'
                    )

        return call.sid
```

And I also have a Node.js application with the Twiml response.

```
const express = require('express');
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;
const urlencoded = require('body-parser').urlencoded;

const app = express();

app.post('/start', (request, response) => {

  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

  const gather = twiml.gather({
    numDigits: 1,
    action: '/confirmation'
  });

  gather.say({
    language:'en-EN'
  }, 'Hello, are you ok?' );

  gather.pause({
    length: 1
  });

  gather.say({
    language:'en-EN'
  }, 'If no press one, if yes press two');

  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());

});

app.post('/confirmation', (request, response) => {

    const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

    if (request.body.Digits) {

        switch (request.body.Digits) {

            case '2':
                twiml.say({
                    language:'en-EN'
                }, 'I am sorry to hear that');


            case '1':
                twiml.say({
                    language:'en-EN'
                }, 'Perfect!');

            default:
                twiml.say({
                    language:'en-EN'
                }, 'Sorry, I don't understand you.');
                twiml.pause({
                    length: 1
                });
                twiml.say({
                    language: 'en-EN'
                }, 'Repeat please');

        }
    }

  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());

});

app.post('/callback', (request, response) => {

    console.log(request.body.CallStatus);
    console.log('--------------------');
    console.log(request.body.AnsweredBy);
    console.log('--------------------');

    response.type('text/xml')
    response.send(request.AnsweredBy)
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The problem is that when I execute the python function. If the user reject the call or doesn't answer, it sends a voicemessage to the answering machine and I would like to avoid it. I would also like to detect in the python code, if the call is rejected or not answered.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't detect whether the call was answered in your python code that creates the call. That will queue up the call to be dispatched by Twilio, so all further events will happen asynchronously to that API call.

For your Node.js application that is receiving the webhook you can check what the current status of the call is by inspecting [the `CallStatus` parameter that is sent as part of the body of the request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters). The `CallStatus` can be one of: "queued", "ringing", "in-progress", "completed", "busy", "failed" or "no-answer" and you can see more about [the `CallStatus` parameter in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#callstatus-values).

To read the `CallStatus` parameter, you'll need to ensure you are using the body-parser middleware properly, `urlencoded` is a function and you need to set the express app to use it.

```
const urlencoded = require('body-parser').urlencoded;

const app = express();
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false });
```

You can then get the call status in your response function.

```
app.post('/start', (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body.CallStatus);
  // and so on
```

Then you can handle it from there.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. The problem is that if the user rejects the call when his phone is ringing, the request.body.CallStatus returns in-progress and then completed. And it final sends a voice message on the answering machine... It happens the same if the user doesn't answer the call.

Comment: Sounds like [answering machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection) might be what you're looking for then. Take a look and see if that will solve your issues.

Comment: I understand. I have put ```app.post('/start', (request, response) => {
 if(request.body.AnsweredBy != 'machine_start'){
  //and the answer } ``` but I don't know what to put in the else for avoid the messege.

Comment: If I don't put the ``` else ``` statement, and all the code is inside the ``` if ```, it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not `if (request.body.AnsweredBy === 'human') { // do what you were before } else { // hangup }`? You can [use TwiML to `<Hangup/>` the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/hangup) if you don't want it to continue

Comment: Yes! That is what I wanted!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: what I dont understand is all of the available status non of them say "answered" so if I understand correcly if I dont get busy fail or no answer it mean it was answered? why there is no simply "answered" status

Comment: @AmirBar that is correct, I don’t know the original reason for those statuses, but my guess is that it’s not possible for Twilio to necessarily say it was “answered” by a person.  So, the status “completed” is vague enough to say a call completed it’s expected flow, without a judgement on what happened on the other end.